# What are the Chrome developer-tools highlight colors?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In past versions of Chrome, the developer tools allowed you to inspect page elements and would highlight them in blue. Recent versions of Chrome highlight elements in blue, but also have green and orange areas as well.

What do the colors mean?

[image]

Comment: This is what I came here for: 
blue #9FC4E7
green #C2DDB6
orange #F8CB9C

Comment: In more recent versions of Chrome, there's also purple:

https://i.imgur.com/DbqWn8i.png

I'm not sure what the purple means?

Comment: @HappyHands31 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252231/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-purple-dashed-line-area

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The colors represent the areas of elements corresponding to the [CSS box-model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

- Blue is the content
- Green is the padding
- Orange is the border
- Red is the margin

(The choice of similar shades of orange and red are probably not the best.)

You can see this in the *Metrics* section of the developer tools (which is hidden by default):

[image]

Answer (score 34):

**Update 2021**

Also purple dashed area is displayed now. It represents the available space to expand:

[image]

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252231/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-purple-dashed-line-area)

Comment: What about the dashed blue (maybe caused by `float: right`)?

Comment: For more details on what that means: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252231/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-purple-dashed-line-area

Answer (score 1):

CSS box model parameters (content/padding/border/margin).

Official docs: [Inspect and Edit Pages and Styles: Examine and edit box model parameters](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/?hl=en#examine-and-edit-box-model-parameters)